# SubFunções Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Como faço para criar sub chamadas nas funções Javascript?

Abaixo segue exemplo de utilização, minha dúvida é como criar uma function desse tipo. Dependendo do que acontecer dentro da rotina "Viajar" é disparada chamada para "Chegada" e/ou "Problema"

```
this.Viajar('são paulo').Chegada(() => {
    console.log('chegou com sucesso')
}).Problema(() => {
    console.log('pneu furou')
});
```

Comment: um if não resolve? Não entendi sua pergunta direito

Comment: Você pode utilizar *Promise*. https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/WJJZMQ?editors=1011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está se referindo na verdade não são funções, são classes, onde as classes possuem métodos dentro delas, veja abaixo:

```
class Ponto {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    static distancia(a, b) {
        const dx = a.x - b.x;
        const dy = a.y - b.y;

        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    }
}

const p1 = new Ponto(5, 5);
const p2 = new Ponto(10, 10);

console.log(Ponto.distancia(p1, p2));
```

Você pode criar classes para manipular valores, com funções prédefinidas para tratar os seus elementos.
Confira outras aplicações em:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Certo, mas eu preciso disparar um método externo mediante um outro método interno, no seu exemplo seria algo como
   
   Ponto.distancia(p1, p2).Retorno((msg) => { console.log('retorno foi: ' + msg;  })